# Loading only ActiveRecord for RSpec model tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec-rails

I want to speed up my model tests. After seeing this 
http://iain.nl/testing-activerecord-in-isolation,   I thought it could 
be achieved if i can only require the active_record rather than 
loading the spec_helper.rb, which loads the whole Rails stack for 
every test file. 
I am using rspec-rails with factory_girl. 
But so far its not working for me. Every time i run a single file the 
whole migrations are getting run, which is not acceptable.And before 
the whole migrations run i am getting some errors. 
Anybody have a better idea?

Comment: This might be useful: http://paul.annesley.cc/2012/03/fast-rspec-slash-rails-tiered-spec-helper-dot-rb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to speed up your tests by not having to reload the Rails environment each time, you should look into using Spork, Guard, and Guard::Spork.  Spork allows you to run a separate, "clean" test server, while Guard enables you to keep it running in the background by observing your files for changes.

Spork: https://github.com/sporkrb/spork

Guard::Spork: https://github.com/guard/guard-spork

The ever-helpful Railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/285-spork

Comment: I used spork and sporkguard for running individual tests and [parallel_tests](https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests) to run the whole test suite.

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar recently.

See if this helps: http://technorattle.wordpress.com/2013/01/10/activerecord-outside-rails/